# how to do less than or equal to in 8085 Assembly language

Tags: assembly, 8085

I'm not sure if all assembly is the same, I have looked this question up already and the language I saw looked different. I am learning to code for the 8085 microprocessor and need to know how take a byte stored in location 4050h and test if its less than or equal to 7Fh, if it is, I need to store 00h in location 5000h. If its greater than 7F, I need to store 01h in location 5000h. I don't need someone to do the whole thing for me, just point me in the right direction. Any help would be great :)

Comment: 8085, 8086, or 8080?

Comment: See the section on Compare Operators in here: http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/intel/MCS80/9800301D_8080_8085_Assembly_Language_Programming_Manual_May81.pdf

Comment: You can do any comparisons with only 1 of the "less than", "greater than", "less than or equal to" or "greater than or equal to" instructions

Answer (score 0):

Unlike 8051 (which I'm used to), 8085 actually has `CMP` instruction to compare `A` with operand, but it is not needed in your case. Condition "less than or equal to 7Fh" actually means "has no bit 7 set", so you just need to rotate value left (so bit 7 becomes bit 0) and bit-and it with 01h.

So it would be something like:

```
LDA 4050h
RLC 
ANI 01h
STA 5000h
```

Comment: IIRC, 8051 also has CMP, of course with only 1 operand because the other would always be register A

Comment: Oh, sorry, it was a mistype. Doesn't change the answer though :)

Comment: @lưu-vĩnh-phúc, no, it doesn't: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_opcodes.htm. But it is off-topic.

Comment: Thank you guys, you have been a great help :)